# Google Sheet Email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I need to send the messages on all the email listed in column A please help ,

```js
var e1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sampling").getRange("A:A");
var email1 = e1.getValue();
var mes1 =  crypto1 + 'our value ' + (changedd * 100) + '  Average value ' + (Sales * 100 );
MailApp.sendEmail(email1, sub1, mes1, mes1);
```

only first cell in Column A get the email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to send emails using `MailApp.sendEmail` by retrieving the email addresses from the column "A" of the sheet of "sampling" in the active Spreadsheet.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the value of `email1` is the cell value of the 1st row of the column "A". I understand that this is your current issue. In this case, you can retrieve the values from the column "A" using `getValues()`.
- And, I thought that the empty values and the duplicated values might be required to be considered.
- About `MailApp.sendEmail(email1, sub1, mes1, mes1)`, when `sub1` is the subject of the email, please use `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body) Because when 4 arguments are used like `MailApp.sendEmail(email1, sub1, mes1, mes1)`, the 2nd argument is the reply-to address. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailto,-replyto,-subject,-body) Please be careful this.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sampling");
var emails = [... new Set(sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((ar, [a]) => {
  if (a) ar.push(a);
  return ar;
}, []))];
var mes1 =  crypto1 + 'our value ' + (changedd * 100) + '  Average value ' + (Sales * 100 );
emails.forEach(email => MailApp.sendEmail(email, sub1, mes1));
```

- In this case, it supposes that the variables of `crypto1`, `changedd`, `Sales` and `sub1` have already been declared. Please be careful this.

#### Note:

- When you want to send the email by including the emails as `cc`, please modify above script as follows.

  - From

    ```
      emails.forEach(email => MailApp.sendEmail(email, sub1, mes1));
    ```
  - To

    ```
      MailApp.sendEmail({subject: sub1, body: mes1, cc: emails.join(",")});
    ```

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body)

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH,

Comment: @john foreign PH Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.